# Call a java method from a javascript file(Spring MVC no jsp)

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring-mvc, spring-framework-beans

I am developing a web app using Java springframework. I have certain buttons on my web page that I need them to fire java methods when they are clicked(No URL redirection). I think I need to use AJAX here because I dont need the page to reload nor to be redirected to any URL.

Here is my java controller code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MainController 
{
   public void run() 
   {   
    System.out.println("Test1");
    System.out.println("Test2");
    System.out.println("Test3");
    System.out.println("Test4");

   }
}
```

Here is my view html code:

```
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-default" onclick="javascriptFunction()">
```

I want the javascriptFunction to call the run method in the MainController class. Both files are in the same project.

Comment: Definitely you need to use Ajax to call the rest service which will then implement the required function. You can learn more about Spring MVC here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/springmvc/index.htm

Comment: You should look at this more like, "make a request to an enpoint" not "Call a java method from a javascript file". It will make things clearer and, yes, give Ajax a shot.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. In general you call to the server side via Ajax, e.g., a call to a route in your MVC app and return (generally) JSON, although you could also return HTML.

Comment: My project is fairly simple:
1. Front-end: an html page(view) that contains one button.
2. Back-end: java.
I am using Java Springwebframework to develop this project. I dont have jsp files, only html with javascript. 
What I need is to link a java method from the main controller to the only button that exists in the view(using javascript). I dont want to reload the page nor to be directed to any other url. So no post or get requests. I think I may need to use Ajax. So how can I do that?

Comment: You seem confused on what you're doing. If you don't have JSP files, so what? I could use any templating engine or none, it doesn't matter. The client, from which the request will come, need not know how the html was rendered.

Comment: Also, what sort of request do you expect to use if you can't use GET or POST to pull/push data? And why do you think using one of those inherently results in a redirection?